# Using select-like mechanism to select variables for distinct call in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, nse

## Desired results

Using simple syntax I filter on `vs` and `am` columns leaving also the `cyl` values.

```
data(mtcars)
dta <- mtcars[,c("vs", "am", "cyl")]
# Desired results
dta %>% distinct(vs, am, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

## Desired syntax

I would like to reverse the syntax above and select distinct observations on *all values excluding the `cyl` column,* corresponding to the example below:

```
dta %>% distinct(vars(-contains("cyl")), .keep_all = TRUE)
```

that naturally does not work:

```
>> dta %>% distinct(vars(-contains("cyl")), .keep_all = TRUE)
   vs am cyl vars(-contains("cyl"))
1   0  1   6      ~-contains("cyl")
2   0  1   6      ~-contains("cyl")
3   1  1   4      ~-contains("cyl")
4   1  0   6      ~-contains("cyl")
5   0  0   8      ~-contains("cyl")
6   1  0   6      ~-contains("cyl")
7   0  0   8      ~-contains("cyl")
```

Comment: @akrun `dim(dta %>% distinct(vs, am, .keep_all = TRUE))` is `4 3` and `dim(dta %>% distinct(UQ(setdiff(names(dta), "cyl")), .keep_all = TRUE))` is **`32 3`** or I'm missing something?

Comment: @akrun Apologies, I made a typo and changed it. Although, the key point should be the same: select all columns minus one in distinct.

Comment: I think I got it wrong.  Apologies from my side.

Comment: @akrun None required; thanks for showing the interest.

Comment: This one is interesting question.

Comment: @akrun I hope this will be answered as it would help me. I reckon I could arrive at similar results by using `sapply(seq_along(names(dta)))` and then running simple filter on each column other than the one I do not want to touch but `dplyr` approach would simplify my life a little bit.

Comment: Your title is misleading. i thought it had to do something with variance :)

Comment: @Sotos Good point, this is now changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind not using `distinct`, then you can use `group_by_at` together with `slice` to get your desired result,i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

dta %>% 
 group_by_at(vars(-cyl)) %>% 
 slice(1L)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   vs, am [4]
#     vs    am   cyl
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     0     8
#2     0     1     6
#3     1     0     6
#4     1     1     4
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing the answer. I will accept as it seems to the only viable solution at the moment. I reckon I could `ungroup` later and arrive at identical result, which was the initial goal.

Comment: Potential alternative would be wrapping this in function, doing: `deparse(substitute(cyl))` and then creating quosures from the remaining columns in `names(dta)` to be passed to `distinc` - not worth the hassle.

Comment: I completely agree. Too much trouble